# Setting browser window size in Watir-webdriver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

How can you specify the size of the browser window opened when you call the following with watir-webdriver?

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This works only for Firefox at the moment:

```
browser.window.resize_to(800, 600)
```

and you can move the browser, too:

```
browser.window.move_to(0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks will try it tomorrow :-)

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I didn't know I needed, too. It really helped with Jarmo's Win32Screenshot capability, too: Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:desktop, :area => [0,0,1024,768])

Comment: @adam: watir-webdriver has screen shots built in: `browser.driver.save_screenshot("file_name.png")`

Comment: Make that two answers I didn't know I needed.  I was experimenting with vanilla watir & Jarmo's library first before pulling it into the latest webdriver script - looks like I would be better-served with this one.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. More gems like these will soon be in my Watir book. http://watir.com/book/ :)

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin When using `b.window.resize_to(400,400)` and `b.driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.jpg")` the screenshot is not saved with the 400x400 and keep the original browser size. Any idea why?

Comment: @Martin: I will reply at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828277/selenium-or-watir-webdriver-how-to-save-resized-screenshot

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin Is there a way to size the window proportionally to the screen or is that outside the scope of Watir? I'd like to have the browser take up half the screen.

Comment: What about IE? How can I maximize IE browser?

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin - Is Watir the same as Watir-Webdriver ? Thanks. PS - I don't want to make a question for this because it will be downvoted.

Comment: Works for PhantomJS too! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I'm using ruby+watir-webdriver and this code works for both FF and IE browsers (I have not checked in others browsers)

```
screen_width = browser.execute_script("return screen.width;")
screen_height = browser.execute_script("return screen.height;")
browser.driver.manage.window.resize_to(screen_width,screen_height)
browser.driver.manage.window.move_to(0,0)
```

Answer (score 7):

I did something like this

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
browser.send_keys :f11
```

Comment: @DavidWest Seems like a hack, but does the job ;).. thanks for the upvote mate :)