# How to Resize current window in Selenium Webdriver with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, window-resize

Does anyone know how to resize current browser window using Ruby? I have searched the internet and haven't found any solid solutions. I have the following below, but it is always ignored.

```
def resizeApplication
  @@driver.execute_script("window.resizeTo(500,500);")
end
```

Comment: if you are refering watir-webdriver then you might look at 
[this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126311/setting-browser-window-size-in-watir-webdriver

Comment: How can I resize current window in Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@@driver.manage.window.resize_to(500, 500)
```

See [Window](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Window) class.

Comment: Excellent thanks very much. Please note that this only works in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved alternatively using Chrome options,

```
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      "chromeOptions" => { args: ["--window-size=414,736"]})
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```