# When running cucumber test; browser TEXT is too small

Tags: ruby, firefox, cucumber, watir, retina-display

I'm running some tests in Watir/Cucumber (Ruby) and when the test executes and the browser window opens the text size causes the page to only take up about 1/4 of browser window. This only happens with Firefox and when I'm displaying through my laptop which is a MBP with retina display; not my secondary monitor.

Any advice would be awesome!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126311/setting-browser-window-size-in-watir-webdriver

Comment: Thanks, I did see that thread and I tried those suggestions but they did not work for me. Since this seemed to be a different question, specific to Firefox and possibly my MBP retina display, I did not think it was a duplicate.

This is a new issue that we are seeing when we run our tests, btw. This is not something we've had issues with prior and we're trying to figure out what changed.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to maximize firefox , won't maximize chrome though

```
 page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Will help you

```
 @browser.window.maximize
```